# Is it possible to use includes() when using the gem called Kaminari pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, pagination, kaminari

I'm on Rails 3.2.11.

I'm trying to avoid N+1 problem with using includes().
However, it seems not working for me while I'm using the gem called Kaminari:(

My code is just like this.

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community)
@codes = Code.includes(user: :profile, :community).where(:community_id => @communities.collect(&:id)).order("users.active_at DESC, codes.created_at DESC").page(params[:page])
```

Tables are associated like this

1 - User has_many :codes, User has_many :communities, has_one :profile
 2 - Code belongs_to :user, Code belongs_to :community
 3 - Community has_many codes, Community belongs_to :user
 4 - Profile belongs_to :user

`current_user.get_up_voted(Community)` fetches all the communities that are belonged by current_user
I'm using the gem called [`acts_as_votable`](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) for this.

In my case, how can I includes user, it's profile, and the community that belongs to code?

Comment: If you're showing a list of communities, wouldn't you want the includes to be the community query?

Comment: @swards in this case, I would like to show many different communities but that are still voted by current_user. So I have to go with Code instead of Community.